# CSS file not being found when referencing it in Spring jsp file

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have an index.jsp file located in 'WEB-INF/jsp/' and I am referencing a CSS file in '/resources/css/'. I have put the path as '../resources/css/styles.css', but the browser can't seem to find it.

When typing the path to the CSS file I can even auto-complete, so Spring seems to be OK with locating it. Any ideas? Do I have to alter anything within my dispatcher-servelet.xml file at all?

Cheers
J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Spring was playing up or something, but I removed the '../' from the start of 'resources' (I swear I tried that many times in the past!) and it worked! I am guessing the browser if referencing it from the root folder and not the jsp file, so no need to go up one level.